# "argument of type ”int(*)()“ is incompatible with parameter of type int" error?

Tags: c++, console-application

So I'm trying to write this code which is supposed to generate a sum of two different numbers and identify whether the player has won or lost or neither according to said sum. And then proceed to calculating the budget of the player according to their status. I keep getting the ""argument of type ”int(*)()“ is incompatible with parameter of type int" error and I'm not sure why.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <string>

using namespace std; 

//prototyping functions
int sum();
int bla(int, int, int, int);
void main()
{
    //declaring variables
    int budget, bet, new_budget;
    string yes_no;

    //inputting budget
    cout << "Please enter your budget: ";
    cin >> budget; 

   //inputting bet
cout << "Please enter your bet: ";
cin >> bet; 

//validating bet and budget
if (bet > budget)
{
    cout << "Error, bet cannot be larger than budget. Please reenter your budget and bet, respectively: ";
    cin >> budget;
    cin >> bet;
}
else //calling functions
{
    double m = sum();
    double n = bla(sum, budget, bet, new_budget);
}

//asks player if they would like play again
cout << "Would you like to play again? Enter Y for Yes or N for No";
cin >> yes_no;

//repeats program
if (yes_no == "Y" && (new_budget > 0))
{
    cout << "Please enter your budget: ";
    cin >> budget;

    cout << "Please enter your bet: ";
    cin >> bet;

    if (bet > budget)
    {
        cout << "Error, bet cannot be larger than budget. Please reenter your budget and bet, respectively: ";
        cin >> budget;
        cin >> bet;
    }
    else
    {
        int sum();
        bool win_or_loss(int sum, double budget, double bet);
    }
}

system("pause");
}

int sum() //calculates the sum of the dice
{
int x;
int y;
int sum;

x = rand() % 7;
y = rand() % 7;

sum = x + y;

cout << "The sum of the two dice is " << sum << endl;

return sum;
}

int bla(int sum, int budget, int bet, int new_budget) //calculates the new budget according to whether the player won or lost or neither
{
bool flag = false; 

if ((sum == 7) || (sum == 11))
{
    cout << "You have won" << endl;
    new_budget = budget + bet;
    flag = true;
}
else if ((sum == 2) || (sum == 3) || (sum == 12))
{
    cout << "You have lost" << endl;
    new_budget = budget - bet;
    flag = false;
}
else
{
    cout << "Neither win or loss, please generate new numbers" << endl;
    int sum();
    flag = false;
}

return new_budget;
}
```

Comment: `bool win_or_loss(int sum, double budget, double bet);` That's not how you call a function... and `int sum();` right before it declares another function called sum taking no parameters and returning it, this is not a variable of type int.

Comment: `int sum() { int sum; /**/ }`, Avoid to use same name for variable and function...

Comment: `int sum(); bool win_or_loss(int sum, double budget, double bet);` -- Maybe you should explain what your intentions are with this code.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to provide a [mcve].

Comment: When you call `bla`: `bla(sum, budget, bet, new_budget);` you're trying to pass the `sum` function as an argument. That's what is producing the error: the compiler expects an `int` and you're giving it a pointer to a function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
int bla(int, int, int, int);
```

`bla` function expects `int` arguments but

```
double n = bla(sum, budget, bet, new_budget);
```

you are passing `sum` as a parameter which is a function. As your `sum` function returns an `int`, you can pass it as `sum()`

```
double n = bla(sum(), budget, bet, new_budget);
```

**Side Note:** Inside `sum` function you have declared a variable named `sum`. Avoid using same name for a function and a variable. It causes ambiguity.